# swift tvOS vertical scroll Grid

Tags: swift, uicollectionview, tvos

I am new to tvOS development and I would like to create a Grid with 4 items per row. The collection should vertically scroll. My challenge is that I'm not sure what to do with the information provided by Apple [here](https://developer.apple.com/design/human-interface-guidelines/tvos/visual-design/layout/) in this doc as there is no example.

In iOS we would use something like:

```
class GridFlowLayout: UICollectionViewFlowLayout {
    
    // here you can define the height of each cell
    let itemHeight: CGFloat = 160
    
    override init() {
        super.init()
        setupLayout()
    }
    
    required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        super.init(coder: aDecoder)
        setupLayout()
    }
    
    /**
     Sets up the layout for the collectionView. 1pt distance between each cell and 1pt distance between each row plus use a vertical layout
     */
    func setupLayout() {
        minimumInteritemSpacing = 1
        minimumLineSpacing = 1
        scrollDirection = .vertical
    }
    
    var itemWidth: CGFloat {
        return collectionView!.frame.width / 4 - 1
    }
    
    override var itemSize: CGSize {
        set {
            self.itemSize = CGSize(width: itemWidth, height: itemHeight)
            
        }
        get {
            return CGSize(width: itemWidth, height: itemHeight)
        }
    }
    
    override func targetContentOffset(forProposedContentOffset proposedContentOffset: CGPoint) -> CGPoint {
        return collectionView!.contentOffset
    }
}
```

Then assign it to the collectionView layout

```
collectionView.collectionViewLayout = GridFlowLayout()
```

Im not sure what to do for tvOS how should I adapt the above code to work for tvOS using programmatic code.

[image: For example]

Comment: This might help https://www.bignerdranch.com/blog/custom-collection-view-layouts-with-tvos-part-2/ Also, Check this video: www.youtube.com/watch?v=JbQ2TOsZaNo. In this video, explanation has been given for UITableView and same steps can be followed for UICollectionView.